# Cannot access SwaggerUI index.html page, but can open api-docs (Spring - Boot)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying a small application to learn spring boot with swagger UI. When i run the program, i can open `http://localhost:8080/api-docs` which shows json output. But when i access `http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html`, it gives Whitelabel Error Page.

What steps i followed:

1- Copied the "dist" folder from the swagger-ui project that is available in GitHub.

2- Renamed the "dist" to "swagger" and put it inside `src/main/public`

3- Changed the path in index.html to "/api-docs".

Below is the screenshot from EclipseLuna IDE and all the program codes,

[image]

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.rajkishan.learnSpring</groupId>
<artifactId>RestfulWithSpring</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>LearnRESTfulSpring</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.rajkishan.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application.java

```
package com.rajkishan;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

/**
 * Spring Boot Starter Class
 *
 */

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

`Greeting.java` is a Normal pojo as in spring-restful-demo provided in https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

GreetingController.java

```
package com.rajkishan;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam (value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name){
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
package com.rajkishan;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.EnableSwagger;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin;
import com.wordnik.swagger.model.ApiInfo;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig {
private SpringSwaggerConfig swaggerConfig;

@Autowired
public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig swaggerConfig){
    this.swaggerConfig = swaggerConfig;
}

@Bean
public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customSwaggerPlugin(){
    return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.swaggerConfig).apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .includePatterns("/greeting/.*");
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo(){
    ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("My Spring Application", 
            "Learning Spring Restful", "termsOfServiceUrl", "contact", "license", "licenseUrl");
    return apiInfo;
 }
}
```

Index.html

```
$(function() {
    var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
    if (url && url.length > 1) {
        url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
    } else {
        url = "/api-docs"
    }
/*Rest of the Code Follows...*/
```

Can you see where i am doing it wrong?
Maybe I have Missed Something?

Comment: I guess you are using using spring boot app, did you add an interceptor of swagger

Comment: @Pulkit: No, i am not using any Interceptor. I tried to add swagger-ui to a spring RESTful tutorial in spring's website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Application` class remove all the annotations and replace it with `@SpringBootApplication` in spring-boot 1.2 and above and a combination of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` for boot versions below 1.2.x. In particular remove the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation as it is interfering with the spring boot auto configuration of the resources, i.e. the one that serves up swagger-ui.

Also, your swagger-springmvc dependency is very outdated you should use at least 1.0.2. On a related note have you considered moving using [springfox](http://springfox.io)? It's the next generation of swagger-springmvc and It also supports swagger 2.0.

Comment: I am starting to learn these things. I do not know how to use spring fox. Can you please give me any leads where i can know how to use it? And how can i find out what is the latest version for "swagger-springmvc". Mainly what i do is follow tutorials i find from google search and try to learn from there.

Comment: This [reference docs](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/) should get you started.

Comment: Also note that I've edited the answer for the version of springboot that you have in your Pom file. If removing the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation solves your problem, i would appreciate it if you mark this as your answer.

Comment: I did the changes. Now swaggerUI starts but i just see the message like "localhost:8080/api-docs" is loading but nothing happens. I think i made mistake somewhere. I will do a clean project again with spring boot 1.2.4 and spring 4.1.6 and let you know.

Comment: I tried with spring boot 1.2.4 and swagger-springmvc version 1.0.2. But i cannot access index.html file. If you want to see what i did: https://github.com/Raj-Kishan/RESTful-Swagger.git. I can open `localhost:8080/api-docs` but dont see any GET Method mapped. It just shows default urls.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks for creating a repo

Comment: I just realized, you need to move to http://springfox.io. 1.0.2 is the last version thats based on swagger 1.2. For swagger 2.0 support you'd need to upgrade